# TRANSACT SQL to PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, plpgsql

I have a lot of functions and stored procedures to export from MS SQL server to PostgreSQL

Can you please help me with this function and giving me the equivalent function in PL/pgSQL for PostgreSQL?

```
USE [METRICS]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnPSR_CtrlNouveauProjet]
(
    @InstanceID int,
    @Month_Param nvarchar(15)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue NVARCHAR(2), @Max_ID_Token int
    DECLARE @Month_Param_Prev nvarchar(15)
    SELECT @Month_Param_Prev = CASE WHEN @Month_Param like '%-08' THEN  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '01-'+@Month_Param) - 2, 0), 105),4,10) 
         ELSE  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '01-'+@Month_Param) - 1, 0), 105),4,10) end 
    DECLARE @KIS_FileName NVARCHAR(100)
    SELECT 
        @KIS_FileName = KI.KIS_FileName 
    FROM 
        PSR_KIS_INSTANCE KI (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        KI.ID_Instance = @InstanceID

    SELECT @Max_ID_Token = MAX(KI.ID_Token) FROM DBO.PSR_KIS_INSTANCE KI (NOLOCK) WHERE KI.KIS_FileName = @KIS_FileName and KI.Reporting_Month = @Month_Param_Prev

    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 
        KI.ID_Instance 
    FROM 
        PSR_KIS_INSTANCE KI (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
        KI.KIS_FileName  = @KIS_FileName
        and KI.Reporting_Month = @Month_Param_Prev 
        and KI.ID_Token = @Max_ID_Token))

    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnValue = ' '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnValue = 'N'
    END

    RETURN @ReturnValue

END
```

Comment: _Can you please help me with this function and giving me the equivalent function in PL/pgSQL for PostgreSQL?_ Can you please send me the money first?

Comment: You could at least post a proper question with table definitions and some explanation and what you have tried and exact version numbers of your software.

Answer (score 1):

My T-SQL is really rusty, but something like this should get you started:

#### This is untested and will not compile

```
create or replace function fnPSR_CtrlNouveauProjet(p_instance_id integer, p_month_param varchar)
  return varchar
as
$body$
declare
   l_return_value VARCHAR(2);
   l_max_id_token integer;
   l_mont_param_prev varchar(15);
   l_kis_filename varchar(100);

   -- I have NO idea what the following is doing.
   SELECT @Month_Param_Prev = 
       CASE WHEN @Month_Param like '%-08' 
         THEN  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '01-'+@Month_Param) - 2, 0), 105),4,10) 
         ELSE  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '01-'+@Month_Param) - 1, 0), 105),4,10) 
       end 

    SELECT ki.kis_filename 
      INTO l_kis_filename
    FROM psr_kis_instance ki
    WHERE ki.id_instance = p_instance_id;

    SELECT MAX(ki.id_token) 
      INTO l_max_id_token
    FROM psr_kis_instance ki 
    WHERE ki.kis_filename = l_kis_filename
      AND reporting_month = l_month_param_prev;

    SELECT count(*)
       INTO l_count 
    FROM psr_kis_instance ki
    WHERE ki.kis_filename = l_kis_filename
      and ki.reporting_month = l_month_param_prev
      and ki.id_token = l_max_id_token;

    if l_count = 1 then 
      l_return_value = ' '
    else
      l_return_value = 'N';
    end if;

    RETURN l_return_value;
END;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Some notes:

- `(NOLOCK)` is not needed in Postgres. Readers never block writers and writers never block readers.
- there is no `NVARCHAR` data type. `VARCHAR` is just as good as long as you created the database with UTF-8
- The `dbo` prefix is also not needed in Postgres. You can however create a schema with that name to make the migration easier if you want.
- get used to the fact that unquoted names are folded to lowercase. So instead of using `CamelCaseIdentifier` adopt the habit to separate words using underscores. Use something  like `fn_psr_ctrl_nouveau_projet`. Unquoted identifiers are not case-sensitive, so you can just as well use `fn_PSR_Ctrl_Nouveau_Projet`.
- I have the feeling that the three SQL statements can be merged into a single one (making this much more efficient), but as you didn't bother to explain what you are doing this is hard to tell.